# memory-mapping pre-defined areas of drive

Tags: c, linux, memory-mapping

I want to read very large chunks of data using memory mapped io.

These large chunks of data are comming from a harddisk, no file system just data.

Now before I start this whole ordeal I want to know 2 things.

1. is it possible to memory map only specific parts into memory after eachother and then read is sequentally? First instance I have a harddrive where I want to read 10 chunks of 100mb but each chunk is separated by 1gb of data. is it possible to memory map those 10 chunks of 100mb one after the other so I can acces it like if they were one after the other?
2. Can I memory map huge amount of data? e.g let`s say I have a 10tb disk. is it possible to memory the entire disk? I use a 64bit OS.

I hope someone can clarify!

Comment: Please specify which operating system you are using as memory mapping is not part of the C programming language but rather of the operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, you can use the `mmap()` system call to map files (even block devices) into memory. If you don't know how `mmap()` works, consult the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) before continuing with this answer.

The `mmap()` call allows you to specify a base address for the mapping you want to create. POSIX specifies that the operating system may take this base address as a hint on where to place the mapping. On Linux, `mmap()` will place the mapping on the address you request if it is a page boundary (i.e. dividable by 4096). You can specify `MAP_FIXED` to make sure that the mapping is placed where you want it, but the kernel might tell you that this is not possible.

You can try to map the chunks you want one-after-another using the approach above but this obviously will only work if your chunks have sizes that are multiples of the page size (i.e. 4096 bytes). I would not advise you to do this as it might break on a different page size / configuration.

Mapping the entire disk should be possible depending on your memory configuration. You might need to configure the overcommiting behavior of your system for this.

I suggest you to try out if mapping the entire disk works.

Comment: Over committing shouldn't be an issue since in this case the memory will be committed directly to the hard disk. That assumes the disk isn't mapped with PROT_WRITE and MAP_PRIVATE, ie. not copy on write.